# How to find out straight lines in a image

Tags: c, perl, matlab, image-processing, imagemagick

I have an image file.(jpg or png)

This is having only 4 colors and few black lines.(600px X 600px image size).
There can be 2 or 4 or 6 black lines.

I need to get the (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) of each black lines.

Can be implemented with perl or c or matlab

Answer (score 8):

Try applying the [Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform). It is especially effective at detecting lines.

Answer (score 0):

One simple possibility to detect lines in images is calculating the [image gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient).

For that calculate the gradient in either x or y direction (depending on the orientation of the lines) and then threshold the gradient to find out whether a black line is present.